# How are the threshold or cutoff points in {Epi} R package selected?

Tags: r, roc

In the `R` package [`{Epi}`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Epi/index.html) the `ROC()` function can generate a plot out of the dataset `aSAH` in in the `{pROC}` package like this:

[image]

with the following commands:

```
require(Epi)
require(pROC)
data(aSAH)
rock = ROC(form = outcome ~ s100b, data=aSAH, plot = "ROC", MX = T)
```

The sensitivity and specificity were calculated for 51 points included in the object `nrow(rock$res)`. In this regard, note that `nrow(aSAH)` is instead 113.

Which points were used to generate `rock$res`?

If we were using the function `roc()` in the package `{pROC}` instead, we could get this via: `roc(aSAH$outcome, aSAH$s100b)$threshold`. But being different packages, they are probably different.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is... of course... in the [package documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Epi/Epi.pdf):

> ***res*** dataframe with variables sens, spec, pvp, pvn and name of the test
> variable. The latter is the unique values of test or linear predictor
> from the logistic regression in ascending order with -Inf prepended.

So what are the unique values:

`points = unique(aSAH$s100b); length(points)  [1] 50` plus the pre-ended `-Inf`!

Nice inkling, but can we prove it... I think so:

```
require(Epi)
require(pROC)
data(aSAH)
rock = ROC(form = outcome ~ s100b, data=aSAH, plot = "ROC", MX = T)

d = aSAH
> head(d)
     gos6 outcome gender age wfns s100b  ndka
 29    5    Good  Female  42    1  0.13  3.01
 30    5    Good  Female  37    1  0.14  8.54
 31    5    Good  Female  42    1  0.10  8.09
points = sort(unique(d$s100b))
> head(points)
[1] 0.03 0.04 0.05 0.06 0.07 0.08
> length(points)
[1] 50

## Logistic regression coefficients:
beta.0 = as.numeric(rock$lr$coefficients[1])
beta.1 = as.numeric(rock$lr$coefficients[2])

## Sigmoid function:
sigmoid =  1 / (1 + exp(-(beta.0 + beta.1 * points)))
sigmoid = as.numeric(c("-Inf", sigmoid))

lr.eta = rock$res$lr.eta
length(lr.eta)
head(lr.eta)
head(sigmoid)

> head(lr.eta)
[1]      -Inf 0.1663429 0.1732556 0.1803934 0.1877585 0.1953526
> head(sigmoid)
[1]      -Inf 0.1663429 0.1732556 0.1803934 0.1877585 0.1953526

## Trying to get the lr.eta number 0.304 on the plot:
> which.max(rowSums(rock$res[, c("sens", "spec")])) 
# 0.30426295405785      18 

## What do we find in row 18 or res?
> rock$res[18,]
                  sens      spec       pvp      pvn     lr.eta
0.30426295405785 0.6341463 0.8055556 0.2054795  0.35    0.304263

## Yet, lr.eta is not the Youden's J statistic or index:
> rock$res[18,"sens"] + rock$res[18,"spec"] - 1
[1] 0.4397019

## Instead, it is the Probability of the outcome at the input with max Youden's index:
## Excluding the "-Inf" introduced by the ROC function (position 17 as opposed to 18):
max.sens.sp.cut = points[17]
1 / (1 + exp(-(beta.0 + beta.1 * max.sens.sp.cut)))  [1] 0.304263 !!!
```

Done!

The `lt.eta` is, therefore, the probability of the outcome at the threshold corresponding to the maximum [Youden's index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Youden%27s_J_statistic).